# why the specialfolder.personal return c:/user/xxx/Documents

Tags: .net, special-folders

I expect the specialfolder.personal returns c:/users/xxx, however in my Windows 7 system, it returns 
c:/users/xxx/Documents. Why? How to get the folder of personal root directory?

Comment: Have you tried `UserProfile` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx):

> Personal: The directory that serves as a common repository for documents. This member is equivalent to MyDocuments.

Instead, you want `SpecialFolder.UserProfile`.

> UserProfile: The user's profile folder. Applications should not create files or folders at this level; they should put their data under the locations referred to by ApplicationData.

### Update

Apparently, this only works in .NET 4. So instead, try this:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile");
```

Comment: There is no SpecialFolder.UserProfile in the SpecialFolder enum.

Comment: It is working by using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(@"USERPROFILE")

Comment: why use two percent sign here?

Comment: Good point. I was thinking of [ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx).

Comment: Why is `UserProfile` suggested off limits for applications?

Comment: @kdbanman My guess is because it's not part of the user's roaming profile like ApplicationData is. LocalApplicationData is the non-roaming counter part. Also, it's not necessarily off limits, just not usually the best place.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
```

Edit: this emum member is present only in Framework 4.0. In earler Framework versions, the following should give the same result:

```
void Main()
{
    var lpszPath = new StringBuilder(260);
    const int UserProfile = 40;
    SHGetFolderPath (IntPtr.Zero, UserProfile, IntPtr.Zero, 0, lpszPath);
    string answer = lpszPath.ToString();    
}

[DllImport("shfolder.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern int SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, int nFolder, IntPtr hToken, int dwFlags, StringBuilder lpszPath);
```

Comment: There is no SpecialFolder.UserProfile in the SpecialFolder enum.